# How do i prove that if $n$ is prime then $Z_n^*$ is a group under multiplication?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I want to prove that if $n$ is prime then $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is a field. I have been told that if $n$ is prime $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is a group under multiplication and thus $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is also a field. Is this statement true?

Moreover if so is there a way of proving if $n$ is prime $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is a group under multiplication?

Comment: Not $\mathbb Z_n$ but the nonzero elements $\mathbb Z_n^*$ forms a multiplicative group. To find an inverse for a nonzero element, use the fact that given two relatively prime integers you can write $1$ as a linear combination of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well just like John pointed out.If $p$ is prime then  $Z_p^*$ is a group under multiplication and $Z_p^*$ consists of all the elements in $Z_p$ except $[0]$ because $[0]$ is not invertible for any $Z_n$.

Notice that $[1]$ is the identity in $Z_n$ in general and so it's the identity in $Z_p$.

Now $[0]$ is not invertible in $Z_n$ because $0x \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ doesn't have a soltuion.

Now $$Z_p^* = \{1,2,......,p-1 \}$$

Notice that $1,2,......,p-1$ are coprime with $p$ because $p$ is a prime.

Now you should know that all these elements are invertible because the equation $ax \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ has a solution if and only if $\gcd(a,p) = 1$ . That's to say that $a$ and $n$ are comprime.

Now it's obvious that all elements in $Z_p^*$ are comprime with $p$ as we stated before and so $ax \equiv \pmod {p}$ has a solution for all $a \in Z_p^*$ and so all elements are invertible in $Z_p^*$ and so $Z_p^*$ is a group under multiplication because

(1) There exists an identity which is $[1]$

(2) All elements are invertible

(3) for all $a,b \in Z_p^*$ $ab \in Z_p^*$

(4) for all $a,b,c \in Z_p^*$, $(ab)c  = a(bc)$

Actually it's a commutative group as well because we do have that $ab = ba$ for all $a,b \in Z_p^*$

Comment: Thanks for your response. Also is $z_n$ a field if $z_n^*$ is a multiplicative group. If so why?

Comment: A field is a commutative ring with unity  and it has the property that every non zero element in the ring is invertible

Now if $Z_n^*$ is a multiplicative group then yes $Z_n$ is a field because. we know that $Z_n$ is a group under addition and every non zero element in $Z_n$ has a multiplicative inverse and hence $Z_n$ is a field.

A ring has two operation (addition and multiplication)

.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be a prime number. The main part of the solution is to prove that for every integer $a$, which is not divisible by $p$, the equation
$$
ax\equiv1\pmod p
$$
has a solution in integers. For this reason observe that the set $\{a,2a,\dotsc,pa\}$ is a complete residue class modulo $p$. And hence one of them equal to one modulo $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be a prime number and $m, n \in \Bbb Z$.

We want to show that if $a \not\equiv 0\pmod p$ and $b \not\equiv 0\pmod p$ then $ab \not\equiv 0\pmod p$, and we can assume that $1 \lt a \lt p$ and $1 \lt b \lt p$.

Since both $a$ and $b$ are less than $p$, their prime factorization can't contain $p$.

Assume to get a contradiction that $p \mid ab$.

Let $a = \alpha_1 \alpha_2 \dots \alpha_{k(m)}$ and $b = \beta_1 \beta_2 \dots \beta_{k(n)}$ be the prime factorizations. Then, by the hypothesis, for some $q \in \Bbb N$

$ pq = ab = \alpha_1 \alpha_2 \dots \alpha_{k(m)} \times \beta_1 \beta_2 \dots \beta_{k(n)}$

But the number $mn$ is divisible by $p$ and has a prime factorization where $p$ does not appear as a factor. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (uniqueness), this is absurd.